# HA and centralized config storage for zeromq - alternatives to zookeeper and doozer

Tags: zeromq, high-availability, doozer

Is there an alternative to zookeeper or doozer that are best of breed?  I do not want to use java and doozer install is rather tough.

I would like a HA service in the spirit of zookeeper and doozer where machines can register there IP address and the type of server e.g. worker or web app.  This will needed for zeromq where workers will need to know the servers to connect.

Thanks

Comment: "doozer install is rather tough" -- not really, see https://github.com/ActiveState/doozerd/wiki/Instructions-to-compile-doozer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider [zpax](https://github.com/cocagne/zpax), it's similar to zookeeper/doozer in basic concept but it's intended for direct embedding into the target application. However, it's still pretty early in the development process. If you have the time and motivation to invest some effort in this arena, it might be worth a look.